# Highcharts - line chart dataLabels on every other point?

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highcharts line graph that has dataLabels configured in the plotOptions. This is all working well and I have a nice label displayed over each point.

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
            return '$' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.round(this.y),0,0,",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, is there a way to set an interval that determines how often the dataLabels appear over the points? I want to show every point in my graph, but due to space constraints, only show the dataLabel every 2 or 3 points.

**Edit:**

Difficulty level: My graph has multiple y-axes, uses datetime for the x-axis, and has irregular data.
http://jsfiddle.net/SQkMW/68/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could just return a blank string if the point x mod 2 is 0, for every 2nd to show up, for example (http://jsfiddle.net/HzYtV/):

```
formatter: function() {
    if(this.point.x % 2 == 0) return '';
    return this.y +'mm';
}
```

For datetime axis you will have to create a variable and increment it manually http://jsfiddle.net/SQkMW/69/

Comment: It looks like that works beautifully for most cases (and I can use on other graphs), but my x-axis is type:datetime and I have multiple y-axes with irregular data. I will amend my question and add a fiddle to reflect this. http://jsfiddle.net/SQkMW/68/

Comment: @Jamie For this case, just create a variable and increment it http://jsfiddle.net/SQkMW/69/

Comment: @Jamie - not sure how to deal with irregular data

Comment: it's good enough for my application, thanks! The irregular data between my two series doesn't seem to be impacting this case.

Comment: You could also use `this.point.index`, it's the zero based index of the point in the data list so it's also good for datetime axes (where `this.point.x` will be in milliseconds) or for irregular values